# Why Auto increment does not work in google sql cloud?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

Hi I am trying to create a table in google sql cloud using this query,Here $email and $sid is dynamic variablle changes according to user.

```
    $productcategory="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".$email."`.`".$email."_".$sid."_product_category`(`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`addeditems` varchar(25) NOT NULL) ENGINE = InnoDB"; 

q5=mysqli_query($sql,$category);
```

This table when I have not added the keyword **AUTO_INCREMENT** created in my sql, But after adding **AUTO_INCREMENT** my table is not created.Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` if you want that column to be the PK.

Comment: Insert not working please check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4705b

Comment: What is not working? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccf1c/1

Comment: I tried this demo sqlfiddle in my google instance table is not created.Should I add this ENGINE = InnoDB  @PaulSpiegel

Comment: You need good reasons not to use InnoDB. Do you get any error message when you try to create the table?

Comment: NO I did not receive any response from the server @PaulSpiegel

Comment: you tagged both "mysql" and "sql-server". So what is it?

Comment: Its mysql sorry for that

Comment: Try also to use `int(11)` or better `int(10) unsigned` instead of `int(20)`. Or `BIGINT`

Answer (score 3):

Q: Why doesn't AUTO_INCREMENT work in google sql cloud?

What you are really asking is why is your CREATE TABLE statement not creating a table when you include the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute in the column definition.

The reason for that is the CREATE TABLE statement is *failing* in google sql cloud. And its failing for same reason it would fail in every MySQL database everywhere.

MySQL requires that an AUTO_INCREMENT column be indexed. Typically, the AUTO_INCREMENT column is either the PRIMARY KEY of the table, or it has a unique index on it.

This is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

> **Note**
>   There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. ...

MySQL returns an error when a statement attempts to violate this rule. The error would be available from mysqli_error function. Your code could perform a conditional test, to check whether the execution of the statement failed or was successful. If it failed, the error message can be retrieved with the mysqli_error function.

On another note, the `int(20)` is a bit odd. The INTEGER type is a 4-byte signed integer. The maximum value is 2**31-1. Converted to decimal, that would require (at most) 10 digits for positive values. The minimum (biggest negative) value would need an extra character for the sign.

The (optional) length specifier for an INTEGER column specifies the display length. It doesn't have any impact on the range of values that can be stored. 
What's odd about it is that the display length is 20, nine more characters than would be needed for any value that can be stored.

If you need an integer type that supports a larger range of values than INTEGER type, you could use BIGINT. That's an 8-byte signed integer. Maximum value supported by BIGINT would be 2**63-1. A display length of 20 makes sense for a BIGINT.

All of the integer types (including BIGINT and INTEGER) support an UNSIGNED attribute, which disallows negative values.